# How do I reference a GameObject from a script inside an instantiated object in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(Fairly new to Unity and C# btw)

So we have a GameObject and let's say we want to move it to x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 FROM a script inside an instantiated (cloned) object.

If I write:

```
public GameObject Obj;
```

I can't actually assign anything to it that is outside of the prefab that I'm instantiating.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'm following, but you could try assigning the object-to-move inside the script that instantiates the prefab. Then once it's created, assign the object-to-move to the public Obj variable. Like this:

```
// Inside your instantiating script
public GameObject obj;
public static void InstantiateWithObj()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(YourPrefab) as GameObject;
    MoveScript moveScript = newObject.GetComponent<MoveScript>();
    moveScript.Obj = obj;
}
```